# read a file in an array java

Tags: java, string, io

here i have a problem in IO . the string ext[] is reading only the last entry off the txt file in this case only jpg.
i want to read all but it reads only the last i have to keep this code in the constructor 
Kindly point out the mistake 
Thanks in advance

```
    /////Text file format 
      txt
      png
      jpg

  ///// file reading code

 String  line;
//// constructor 
  public MainFrame(){
    initComponents();
    fileChooser=new JFileChooser();
  try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("ext.txt"));
     while (in.hasNextLine()) {
          line = in.nextLine(); 
        } System.out.println(line);
           String ext[] = line.split("\\n"); /// can't read all the strings from file.

     FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES",ext); 
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);} 
  catch(IOException io){

  }
  }
```

Comment: check your brackets.....

Comment: Your closing curly brace should be after `line.split("\\n");`

Comment: No there i have problem with string over righting and scope of varibles

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `String ext[]`

Every time you loop through you overwrite the variable `ext[]`. I think instead you should do:

```
try {
ArrayList<String> ext = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("ext.txt"));
 while (in.hasNextLine()) {
      line = in.nextLine(); 
    } System.out.println(line);
       ext.append(line.split("\\n"));
```

You may have to do some syntax work cause I haven't worked in java for a bit but I think this is right

Comment: I need the string var only as the FIleNamefilter method only supports String var .

Comment: Thanks for you help

But i is done by simple string concatenation function.
/////////////////////
 while (in.hasNextLine()) {
          line = in.nextLine(); 
           line2= line2 += line+"\n";

Comment: @user3078848 ah ok you didn't want to put your strings into an array but instead one long string?

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file line by line in java is normally done with a BufferedReader. So you can also handle exceptions and you always close the file after reading.

Here is an example, out of my head, but I strongly recommand you to read more about working with files. A great start is the oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

```
//a collection that stores the lines
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>()
BufferedReader buf = null;
try{
    buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = null;

    while((line = buf.readLine()) != null){
        lines.add(line);
    }
//if something goes wrong   
catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    //closing the buffer, so that the file isnt locked anymore
    if(buf != null)
       buf.close();

}
```